# kcov not showing any code coverage

Tags: code-coverage, kcov

I'm trying to run kcov on my executable and whenever I run it I only get code coverage for standard c++ code like iostream.  If I exclude that then I get "Code covered: NaN%" with 0 lines executed.

I'm trying to run on linux by using

${kcovExe} --exclude-path=${gcclibs} ${outputDir} ${myExe} ${args}

Ive looked through the [git page](https://github.com/SimonKagstrom/kcov) and Ive tried to use --include-path to point to my source code but I cant seem to get it to work.

What do I need to do to get my code to show up in the coverage report?

Edit: for clarification I am building in one environment and running in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that copying the code over to where I am running and using the

--replace-src-path=OriginalSourcePath:NewSourcePath

option works.